# Java 8 chain lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am playing with java lambdas and here is my current code:

```
public class TypeChecker<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class clazz;
    private UnaryOperator<T> callback;

    private TypeChecker(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static TypeChecker<String> when(String v) {
        return new TypeChecker<>(v);
    }

    public static TypeChecker<Integer> when(int v) {
        return new TypeChecker<>(v);
    }

    public TypeChecker<T> is(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        return this;
    }

    public TypeChecker<T> then(UnaryOperator<T> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        return this;
    }

    public void execute() {
        if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
            callback.apply(value);
        }
    }
}

TypeChecker.when("123").is(String.class).then(s -> {
    return s;
}).execute();

TypeChecker.when(123).is(Integer.class).then(n -> {
    return n;
}).execute();
```

Here I am just checking the instanceOf the variable and its working fine. What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
TypeChecker.when(123)
.is(String.class).then(s -> {
    return s;
})
.is(Integer.class).then(n -> {
    return n;
})
.is(Double.class).then(d -> {
    return d;
}).execute();
```

Now how do I chain it? I am confused with where should I save the `Clazz` & `Callbacks`? Should I store it in a map and at the execute method just iterate and check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question reminds me of the [lambda expression builder pattern](http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2014/11/02/builder-pattern-with-java-8-lambdas/). I would introduce a new interface to do the `is().then()` operation and add it to a `Map` in the `TypeChecker` like:

```
class Matcher<T> {

  private final Map<Class<?>, UnaryOperator> mapping = new HashMap<>();
  private final T value;

  private Matcher(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static <T> Matcher<T> when(T v) {
    return new Matcher<>(v);
  }

  public <S> Condition<S> is(Class<S> clazz) {
    return callback -> {
      mapping.put(clazz, callback);
      return this;
    };
  }

  public void execute() {
    mapping.forEach((key, val) -> {
      if (key.isInstance(value)) {
        val.apply(value);
      }
    });
  }

  interface Condition<S> {
    Matcher<?> then(UnaryOperator<? super S> callback);
  }
}
```

---

Easily tested with and should produce your desired results:

```
Matcher.when(123).is(String.class).then(s -> {
  System.out.println("STRING");
  return s;
})
        .is(Integer.class).then(i -> {
  System.out.println("INTEGER");
  return i;
}).execute();
```